# Chrome Heap Snapshot - What causes the (string) objects to be created?

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

When I take a Heap Snapshot of http://google.com I can see over 16k "(string)" objects or 0.8MB Retained Size

[image: Google.com Heap Snapshot]

When I run this on my own website I see over 150k "(string)" or 36MB Retained Size. The largest of these "(string)" objects contain the javascript code I have loaded.

[image: My Website Heap Snapshot]

Since my JS code is already in the (compiled code) section why do I also see the code here as a string?

I cannot find any information on what the "(string)" objects relate to. Obviously they relate to strings but why is my Javascript code stored as a string when it is stored in (compiled code) already.